# PoDoFo AES Encryption

Tags: encryption, podofo

I'm trying to use PoDoFo (0.9.2) to decrypt (and later encrypt) files. However, the code does not support AESV2 which is currently the de-facto standard. I didn't find any material about this issue and I was wondering if anyone tried to tackle it or to patch the library to make it usable.

Comment: AESV2? What does the V2 mean?

Comment: AESV2 means AES with key length of 128 bits (and few other characteristics defined by the PDF standard)

Comment: 0.9.3 seems to support AESV2. see class PdfEncryptAESV2. http://podofo.sourceforge.net